# Something is wrong in JavaScript object declaration

Tags: javascript

This code:

```
var doc = {
  foldPrompt: function(folded) {
    return folded ? "Click to unfold" : "Click to fold"
  },
  createFoldButtons: function() {
    var prompt = foldPrompt(true); //The error is here
    $("#ComparisonTable td.secrow").each(function(index, td){
      $(td).prepend($('<img src="minus.gif" class="foldbtn" alt="'+prompt+'" title="'+prompt+'">'));
    });
  }
}
```

gives me an error: `Undefined variable: foldPrompt`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`foldPrompt` is not a variable; it's a property of `doc`, and you need an object reference to access properties of that object.

If someone calls `doc.createFoldButtons()`, then the `this` context variable will point at the same object that the `doc` variable does.  So, replace `foldPrompt(true)` with `this.foldPrompt(true)`.

Comment: Ah I just spotted, "replace `foldPrompt(true)` with `this.foldPrompt(true)`." Never mind

Comment: @cdhowie: anyway, you'll see a preview which you can approve or reject.

Comment: @Paul Not if the editor has the required reputation; in that case the edit would be performed immediately and without any approval.